# Is there an easy way to do 4 at a time in a php foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have this php foreach loop

```
<?php $all_news = $this->db->query("Select * from news"); ?>
<div class="inner">             
foreach($all_news as $key=>$news){?>
  <div class="news <?php echo ($key%2==1)? 'odd': 'even'?>">
  <div class="news_img">....<?php echo $news['title'] ?>
```

But the problem is the $all_news may have 20 results or so but the design only allows me to put for 4 news blocks in each inner div...is there a way make this happen so i have only 4 news divs in each inner div

Comment: So you want your 20 results split up into 5 divs?  Or you want only 4 results in 1 div total?

Comment: yes i want it split in 5 divs...not one div

Comment: Why not just keep count? `if ($loop % 4 == 3) echo '<div...'`

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php 

$all_news = $this->db->query("Select * from news"); 

echo '<div class="inner">';

$c = count($all_news);
for($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++){
    <div class="news <?php echo ($i%2==1)? 'odd': 'even'?>">
    <div class="news_img">....<?php echo $news['title'] ?>
    if($i % 4 == 3)
        echo '</div><div class="inner">';
}

echo '</div>';

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Change your query to only return 4 rows:</strike>

```
SELECT * FROM news LIMIT 4
```

Alternatively you can change your for-loop.

```
for($i = 0; $i < min(4, count($all_news)); $i++)
{?>
  <div class="news <?php echo ($i%2==1)? 'odd': 'even'?>">
  <div class="news_img">....<?php echo $all_news[$i]['title'];

<?}
```

[edit]

See what you mean now. Create two loops:

```
<?
$index = 0;
while ($index < count($all_news))
{
  $news = $all_news[$index];

  ?>Start outer div<?

  for ($item = 0; $item < 5; $item++)
  {
    ?>Inner div with news item <? echo $news['title'];
  }

  ?>End outer div<?
  $index++;
}
```

Comment: but how do i do the next 4, I need 5 inner divs

Comment: Edit: Removed the break from the loop and used `min` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use two `for` loops:

```
<?php $all_news = $this->db->query("Select * from news"); ?>
<?php for($i = 0, $l = count($all_news); $i < $l; $i+=4): ?>
    <div class="inner">
    <?php for($j = $i; $j < $i+4; $j++): ?>
        <div class="news <?php echo ($j%2==1)? 'odd': 'even'?>">
        <div class="news_img">....<?php echo $all_news[$j]['title'] ?>
    <?php endfor;?>
    </div>
<?php endfor;?>
```

Another option would be [`array_chunk` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

Answer (score 1):

The laziest way would be to just check whether or not you've already done four in the current div on the fly. If you have, close the current div and start a new one:

```
<div class="inner">
<?php
foreach ($all_news as $key => $news) {
    if ($key % 2) {
        $oddEven = 'odd';
    } else {
        $oddEven = 'even';
        if ($key && $key % 4 === 0) {
            echo '</div><div class="inner">';
        }
    }

    echo "<div class=\"news $oddEven\">";
    // ...
}
?>
</div>
```

Note that this assumes `$all_news` has an element at `0`, so it makes sure that it doesn't close the first, empty div.