# PHP - Adding divs to a foreach loop every 4 times, working with $post_object

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I am building a wordpress page (based on quark, using ACF) showing info from other posts using     `foreach(get_field('exhibitions') as $post_object)`

I want the 'col grid_3_of_12-divs' containing info from other posts to group up in divs, with four in each div. A similar problem as the author of this question had: [Is there an easy way to do 4 at a time in a php foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059002/is-there-an-easy-way-to-do-4-at-a-time-in-a-php-foreach-loop)

I have tried with array_chunk, but can't seem to make it without messing with the retrieving of info from the other posts.

Can someone help me with this?

I am a self taught php beginner, so please excuse me if my code is stupid..

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="site-content row clearfix" role="main">

    <div class="col grid_12_of_12">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php foreach(get_field('exhibitions') as $post_object): ?>

                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_object->ID); ?>">
                    <div class="col grid_3_of_12">
                        <h3 class="exhibition title"> <?php echo $post_object->short_title?> </h3>

                        <?php $attachment_id = $post_object->thumbnail;
                        $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' ); ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>">

                        <p class="exhibition short desc"> <?php echo $post_object->short_description?> </p>
                    </div>
                </a>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

                <?php content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a counter. Then when the counter is at the right spot, add a close or open div.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="site-content row clearfix" role="main">

  <div class="col grid_12_of_12">

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php $counter = 0; /* ADD THIS */ ?>
        <?php foreach(get_field('exhibitions') as $post_object): ?>
          <?php if ($counter % 4 == 0): /* ADD THIS */ ?>
            <div class="group-of-4-posts-wrapper">
          <?php endif; ?>

            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_object->ID); ?>">
                <div class="col grid_3_of_12">
                    <h3 class="exhibition title"> <?php echo $post_object->short_title?> </h3>

                    <?php $attachment_id = $post_object->thumbnail;
                    $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' ); ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>">

                    <p class="exhibition short desc"> <?php echo $post_object->short_description?> </p>
                </div>
            </a>
          <?php if ($counter % 4 == 3): /* ADD THIS */ ?>
            </div>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php $counter++ ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php 
          // this closes the div if there is not a number of posts that is evenly
          // divisable by 4, like 11 posts. with 11 posts, the last post would have
          // ($counter % 4 == 3) equal to false, because $counter % 4 would = 2
          // adding this, closes the div, if it was not already closed
          if ($counter % 4 != 0): /* ADD THIS.  */ 
        ?>
          </div>
        <?php endif; ?>


            <?php content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: i was just looking for something like this. You got up vote from me because the counter if there is like 11 posts.